# Hardcoding OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have to generate a binary search tree of size 7 and height 3. However, my answer only has to be hard-coded, not a function that generates one.

so

```
let bst_size7_height3 =
```

What exactly is meant by hardcoding this?

Comment: Hardcoding refers to how you get data. By having your data right in the code, you're "hardcoding" the data. This is opposed to generating the data or retrieving it from an external source (e.g., from a file, from user input, the internet, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the tree will just be an expression in your program. Here is a hardcoded list of three numbers:

```
let numbers = [2; 1; 0]
```

Here is a function to calculate a list of numbers:

```
let rec downfrom n = if n < 0 then [] else n :: downfrom (n - 1)

let numbers2 = downfrom 2
```